# dyld loading system frameworks in addition to private ones of the same name on os x lion

Tags: cocoa, macos, webkit, osx-lion

I'm making an application that depends on webkit, with some modifications to the webkit code.  Thus, I need to use a private framework.  I've made the install path of the framework relative to the executable using the @executable_path directive.

On Snow Leopard, everything works perfectly.  However, on OS X Lion, dyld loads the system webkit (the one used by Safari) *in addition* to my private framework.  This extra load only happens after I right click on the WebView and select "Inspect Element."  I would have to do some deeper debugging to figure out which import exactly is causing dyld to go hunting.  In the build output, I see no indication of linking to the external webkit, so I'm at a loss as to why this is happening, especially since it worked on Snow Leopard.

I don't want to change the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable as this application needs to be distributed to other machines - users should be able to just run the app.

I suppose I could change the name of the framework and see if that fixes the issue.  I'll update this question with the result of investigating the symbol that causes dyld to go looking for the system webkit, as well as making the framework name unique, but any thoughts here would be helpful.

Comment: i found out that Lion is loading the DataDetectors framework, and that seems to be dependent on the system WebKit framework.  i would like to stop lion from loading those frameworks, because the fundamental problem is that objective c classes implemented in WebKit will be duplicated, regardless of my private framework having a unique name.

another option is to somehow make DataDetectors use my private framework, but i'm not sure that's possible?

Comment: I have the exact same problem did you ever figure this one out?